# HtmlEditor with a custom toolbar which includes support for image

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want a htmleditor that get image at local and web!

I use Ajaxcontroltoolkit, but it get image at local. I can add a image url for it ??

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/). There are already many questions in SO reated to this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, But i use for asp. it is only get url!

Comment: Check the demo.It has option to upload images too

Comment: yes, demo work , but when i use sample i get error "access denied"